# How can I speed up this system?

Tags: gnome, nvidia, performance

I'm running a "nettop" computer which is a rather low-end performer. It can probably run better (=faster) than it does simply by adjusting it in some way, because I guess that the standard installation includes things that I don't need which slow the system down.

I think the biggest problem is the graphics... I've had to ditch Unity because it demanded way too much of the machine. I'm now running plain **"Gnome Fallback (no effects)"** and that helped immensely, but when I run only Firefox with 15 open tabs (no browser extensions) and no other apps, the system is still pretty lame.

These are the specs:

- Intel Atom CPU D525 @ 1.80GHz × 4
- Nvidia ION/PCIe/SSE2
- 2,0 GiB RAM
- Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit

Being a nettop, its hardware can't be replaced or expanded. It already has the maximum RAM.
I am configuring a new computer as my primary machine (because this one just sucks too much) but I still want to get some decent use out of this one.

**What are the most obvious, most efficient performance-boosting software adjustments I can make?**

Comment: Thank you! Somehow this didn't show up in my search.

Comment: No problem. This is a general question and so harder to search for.